# error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++14' (Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++

I am using c++ 11 i guess as per code::blocks. I was looking for a way to update to C++ 14. I found a way on one of the threads where it told me to add a flag in the compiler settings

```
-std=c++14
```

My default compiler is set to GNU GCC.
However after i tested a C++ 14 feature program it showed me the following error:

```
error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++14'
```

Can anyone help me with this ? I was unable to find a solution online.
Also if what i did was wrong , is there any other way to switch to C++ 14?

Comment: The only way is to use a compiler that supports C++14. You need to use a newer g++ version. Or you try `-std=c++1y` instead, but even if it is supported by your version it is not as complete as if you'd use a more modern compiler version.

Comment: Okay. Would you suggest i update my compiler to a newer version or get a better compiler?

Comment: Update it. You probably have MinGW, so I suggest latest MinGW-w64.